# Windows doesn't recognize node anymore after installing the latest version

Tags: node.js, path, environment-variables

I installed the latest (stable) version of Node and now I get the

```
"'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

" in my terminal.

I have:

```
C:\Users\myuser\appdata\roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

in my system environment variables in the PATH value.
I have also restarted my computer.

I'm using Windows 8.1

What else can I do? I don't remember how I got this to work half a year ago with the older version of Node.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by giving admin rights to my normal user and removing everything node related and then installing latest node again with my now administrator-privileged user account.